# jQuery UI Scrollable - drag-item position and index bug with multiple vertical scrollable parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**Info:**

Like the title says, there are multiple parent divs (.drag-w1) and I’m using `overflow-y:auto` with `overflow-x:hidden` as there will be multiple items (.item-archive). The items will be sortable between the parent divs. I tried to find out a solution, but nothing worked.

**Problem:**

On drag (or sorting) the item (.item-archive) from one parent div (.drag-w1) to the other, the items are hiding behind the parent divs although, it shows up after dropping. If I’m not using overflow css attribute the items don’t have indexing problem, but that’s not what I want, I really want the items to scroll within the parent div without the items to hide while dragging from one parent div to the other. If I remove `scroll:false` or change it to `true` in the javascript, then the item scrolls within the parent divs until it is dropped on another div.

**Tried:**

1. Adding z-index to css of .item-archive
2. Adding zIndex to the javascript without `drag and stop function`

**Codes:**

```js
$('.drag-tasks').sortable({
    items: "> .item-archive",
    connectWith: '.drag-tasks',
    handle: '.item-top',
    drag:function () {
 $('.item-archive').css('z-index', '10001');
 $(this).addClass('droped');
    },
    stop:function () {
 $('.item-archive').css('z-index', '1');
 $(this).removeClass('droped');
    },
    scroll: false,
    snapMode: 'inner',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    forceHelperSize: true,
    helper: 'original',
    appendTo: 'body'
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
.scroll-wrapper {
    font-family: arial;
    position: relative;
    display: black;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 650px;
}
.drag-w1 {
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    max-width: 497px;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
.sort-col-head-wrapper {
    background-color: #212121;
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0 -10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 55px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.drag-tasks {
    display: block;
    max-height: 600px;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.item-archive {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 105px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 19px;
    max-width: 497px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.item-top {
    display: block;
    height: 57px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    cursor: move;
    padding: 10px 10px 0;
    background: #f3f3f3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroll-wrapper">
    <div class="drag-w1">
        <div class="sort-col-head-wrapper">
         Headline
        </div>
        <div class="drag-tasks">
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body11
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body12
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body13
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body14
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body15
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body16
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drag-w1">
        <div class="sort-col-head-wrapper">
         Headline
        </div>
        <div class="drag-tasks">
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body21
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body22
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body23
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drag-w1">
        <div class="sort-col-head-wrapper">
         Headline
        </div>
        <div class="drag-tasks">
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body31
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body32
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body33
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question:**

How can I make this work?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/367qthu2/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with code but you add a `css` attribute `position: relative;` in many classes so just do one thing remove or comment it and you are done.

```js
$('.drag-tasks').sortable({
    items: "> .item-archive",
    connectWith: '.drag-tasks',
    handle: '.item-top',
    drag:function () {
 $('.item-archive').css('z-index', '10001');
 $(this).addClass('droped');
    },
    stop:function () {
 $('.item-archive').css('z-index', '1');
 $(this).removeClass('droped');
    },
    scroll: false,
    snapMode: 'inner',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    forceHelperSize: true,
    helper: 'original',
    appendTo: 'body'
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
    .scroll-wrapper {
        font-family: arial;
        --position: relative;
        display: black;
        width: 2000px;
        height: 650px;
    }
    .drag-w1 {
        background-color: #d5d5d5;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 5px;
        max-width: 497px;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        --position: relative;
        width: calc(100% - 30px);
    }
    .sort-col-head-wrapper {
        background-color: #212121;
        display: block;
        height: 55px;
        margin: 0 -10px 10px;
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 55px;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
    .drag-tasks {
        display: block;
        max-height: 600px;
        min-height: 600px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        --position: relative;
    }
    .item-archive {
        background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 105px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-right: 19px;
        max-width: 497px;
        --position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .item-top {
        display: block;
        height: 57px;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        --position: relative;
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        cursor: move;
        padding: 10px 10px 0;
        background: #f3f3f3;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroll-wrapper">
    <div class="drag-w1">
        <div class="sort-col-head-wrapper">
         Headline
        </div>
        <div class="drag-tasks">
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body11
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body12
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body13
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body14
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body15
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body16
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drag-w1">
        <div class="sort-col-head-wrapper">
         Headline
        </div>
        <div class="drag-tasks">
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body21
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body22
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body23
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drag-w1">
        <div class="sort-col-head-wrapper">
         Headline
        </div>
        <div class="drag-tasks">
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body31
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body32
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="item-archive">
                <div class="item-top">
                    Body33
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sigh!!! That was easy and worked like charm. I just had to remove `position:relative` from `drag-tasks` as I really need on other elements as I've a lot of absolute positioned elements inside it. Thanks for your help @dom

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, the problem seems to be caused by the `override` property.

I circumvented this issue using `display: inline;` for the class `.drag-tasks`.

```
.drag-tasks {
    display: inline; // use 'inline' instead of block
    max-height: 600px;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
    position: relative;
}
```

Now its draggable, but not droppable, so you need to edit/override the jQuery-ui function which checks the `display: block` status of the `.drag-tasks` and make it work with `inline` property too. Hope this points you in the right direction.